# Hidden dimension key vs. attribute key

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a person dimension with a email alias field in it. This field is unique and there is also an instance ID in my dimension table. I am wondering if there is any performance difference between creating an attribute with a key referencing the instance id, and name referencing the alias vs. creating a hidden attribute in my dimension called "instance ID" and using that to define my dimension relationships.

Won't the cube just use the instance ID in processing within both cases?